# error: cannot find symbol class Crashlytics and Fabric

Tags: android, crashlytics, google-fabric

I'm following Fabric official documentation to add crashlytic, I had successfully added everything in gradle.build file but now when I'm trying to write `Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());`

it says :

```
 Error:(163, 31) error: cannot find symbol class Crashlytics
Error:(163, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable Fabric
Error:Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

this is my gradle.build file

```
....
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.51'
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }

}
dependencies {
    ....
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.24.3'

    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }

}

android {

compileSdkVersion 22

buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.com"
    ....
}

}
dependencies {
......
   compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.0@aar') {
    transitive = true
  }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Also tried clean project/ rebuild and e.t.c but same problem every time

Comment: Please share your gradle

Comment: ok, updated my question

Comment: have you added io.fabric.ApiKey to your manifest @ Jemo ?

Comment: yes, i added ...

Comment: try to update your fabric plugin in studio @ Jemo

Comment: @A.N.T its already updated v 4.1.1

Comment: have you imported these ?  import com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics;
import io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric;  @ Jemo

Comment: ouf, I tried invalidate caches / restart and now works perfectly :/ thanks anyway

Answer (score 8, accepted):

fixed ! it was the Android Studio's fault.

Solution:

**File-> invalidate caches / restart**

after that everything worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

try to add

```
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
```

and customize your gradle according official doc https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/build-tools.html#gradle-advanced-setup

Comment: the Fabric SDK and old versions of the Firebase Crashlytics SDK will stop sending crashes for your app

Answer (score 0):

---

apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
use this but at the bottom

Comment: pls do not post a duplicate answer